# numpy generic in-place operations

Tags: optimization, numpy

Numpy supports a lot of in-place operations with its *=, /=, +=, -=, etc. operations, but what about an operation that doesn't have such a form, like x = f(x), where f is just some T->T function, and T is the type of a single element of x? Example:

```
x = np.sin(x)
```

allocates storage it doesn't need to allocate.

Answer (score 2):

It turns out all numpy ufuncs, which is most T->T functions, have the option of specifying the output of the operation in the function call after the input, letting you put the result wherever you want, including pre-existing arrays or back in the original array! If your arrays are huge, this could save a sizeable amount of memory.

```
>>> tau = 6.2831853071795862
>>> x = sp.linspace(0, tau, 13)
>>> sp.sin(x, x)
array([  0.00000000e+00,   5.00000000e-01,   8.66025404e-01,
         1.00000000e+00,   8.66025404e-01,   5.00000000e-01,
         1.22464680e-16,  -5.00000000e-01,  -8.66025404e-01,
        -1.00000000e+00,  -8.66025404e-01,  -5.00000000e-01,
        -2.44929360e-16])
>>> x
array([  0.00000000e+00,   5.00000000e-01,   8.66025404e-01,
         1.00000000e+00,   8.66025404e-01,   5.00000000e-01,
         1.22464680e-16,  -5.00000000e-01,  -8.66025404e-01,
        -1.00000000e+00,  -8.66025404e-01,  -5.00000000e-01,
        -2.44929360e-16])
>>>
```

Tada! It remains to be seen, however, if numpy actually reused the memory in x or allocated temporary storage, thus defeating the purpose. The documentation wasn't clear on this. In fact the documentation barely mentioned this functionality at all, and didn't give any examples of its usage. More research is needed.

Comment: It is truly in-place, with perhaps a smallish intermediate buffer. Time both approaches and you should see the performance benefit (30% faster for `np.sin` of a 1000 item array on my system).

Comment: Impressive! I wasn't actually expecting much of a time performance gain---only a memory performance gain, though I suppose, if the memory savings let you jam your entire operation into the L1 cache, you'll get both.